# Using Lapack with 128 bit precision

Tags: c++, fortran, lapack, 128-bit

I am trying to use [Lapack](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) for a 128 bit precision calculation of a matrix [singular value decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition) (SVD) and I found out that there is some black compiler magic to accomplish this. The Intel Fortran compiler (ifort) supports the option `-r16` which instructs the compiler to take all variables declared as `DOUBLE PRECISION` to be 128 bit reals. So I compiled Lapack and BLAS using:

```
ifort -O3 -r16 -c isamax.f -o isamax.o
ifort -O3 -r16 -c sasum.f -o sasum.o
...
```

To incorporate this in my program (which is C++) I can use the Intel C++ compiler (icc) with the option `-Qoption,cpp,--extended_float_type` which creates a data type `_Quad` that is a 128 bit floating point variable. My SVD example looks like this:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "vector"

using namespace std;
typedef _Quad scalar;

//FORTRAN BINDING
extern "C" void dgesvd_(char *JOBU, char *JOBVT, int *M, int *N,
    scalar *A, int *LDA,
    scalar *S,
    scalar *U, int *LDU,
    scalar *VT, int *LDVT,
    scalar *WORK, int *LWORK, int *INFO);

int main() {
    cout << "Size of scalar: " << sizeof(scalar) << endl;
    int N=2;
    vector< scalar > A(N*N);
    vector< scalar > S(N);
    vector< scalar > U(N*N);
    vector< scalar > VT(N*N);

    // dummy input matrix
    A[0] = 1.q;
    A[1] = 2.q;
    A[2] = 2.q;
    A[3] = 3.q;
    cout << "Input matrix: " << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for(int j = 0;j < N; j++) 
            cout << double(A[i*N+j]) << "\t";
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;

    char JOBU='A';
    char JOBVT='A';
    int LWORK=-1;
    scalar test;
    int INFO;

    // allocate memory
    dgesvd_(&JOBU, &JOBVT, &N, &N,
        &A[0], &N,
        &S[0],
        &U[0], &N,
        &VT[0], &N,
        &test, &LWORK, &INFO);
    LWORK=test;
    int size=int(test);
    cout<<"Needed workspace size: "<<int(test)<<endl<<endl;
    vector< scalar > WORK(size);

    // run...
    dgesvd_(&JOBU, &JOBVT, &N, &N,
        &A[0], &N,
        &S[0],
        &U[0], &N,
        &VT[0], &N,
        &WORK[0], &LWORK, &INFO);
    // output as doubles
    cout << "Singular values: " << endl;
    for(int i = 0;i < N; i++)
        cout << double(S[i]) << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "U: " << endl;
    for(int i = 0;i < N; i++) {
    for(int j = 0;j < N; j++)
        cout << double(U[N*i+j]) << "\t";
    cout << endl;
    }
    cout << "VT: " << endl;
    for(int i = 0;i < N; i++) {
    for(int j = 0;j < N; j++)
        cout << double(VT[N*i+j]) << "\t";
    cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

compiled with

```
icc test.cpp -g -Qoption,cpp,--extended_float_type -lifcore ../lapack-3.4.0/liblapack.a ../BLAS/blas_LINUX.a
```

Everything works fine this far. But the output is:

```
Size of scalar: 16
Input matrix: 
1       2
2       3

Needed workspace size: 134

Singular values: 
inf
inf

U: 
-0.525731       -0.850651
-0.850651       0.525731
VT: 
-0.525731       0.850651
-0.850651       -0.525731
```

I checked that U and VT are correct, but the singular values are obviously not. Has anyone got an idea why this happens or how one could circumvent it?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does this example work correctly with ordinary double precision arithmetics?

Comment: @Zhenya Yes it does. It calculates the correct singular values when computed with ordinary double precision. (4.23607, 0.236068)

Comment: In that case, I'd check the `DBDSQR` routine: as far as I can see from the source of the reference implementation (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/double/dgesvd.f), it's computing the singular values given the `U` and `VT` matrices.

Comment: What kind of computation are you doing that requires 128bits float precision?

Comment: Actually I resolved the issue by now. It was, to my shame, due to an error I introduced to the make.inc of lapack, which lead to not all files being compiled with the -r16 option. Specifically the files which needed to be compiled without optimization. They have got an extra "compile-options" variable which I overlooked. Never the less, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

When using external libraries with extended precision, also check whether they use old-style **d1mach.f, r1mach.f, i1mach.f** to get information on machine arithmetic. There may be some values to tweak here.

It can't be a problem with Lapack, which uses dlamch.f (here http://www.netlib.org/lapack/util/dlamch.f), which uses Fortran 90 intrinsics to get these machine constants.

But it may become problematic for example with BLAS or SLATEC, if you use them.